# how to add multiple attribute to blueimp upload input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, blueimp

We are using blueimp file uploader to upload files.

I am able to drag & drop multiple files and the uploader uploads all the files.

However I am not able to select multiple files on browse window. 
The reason is the input field rendered does not have multiple attribute.

```
<input class="form-control d2-ctl d2-upload-file-control" type="file">
```

I am wondering how to add it.
Am I missing any settings, please advise?

Regards..

Comment: this html is rendered by blueimp???

Comment: thanks for the reply, and yes this is the input control rendered by blueimp

Comment: can u post some more code plz???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your input field be

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```